# No longer able to deploy my app to my test device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I’ve been using my test device (iPhone 6s+, I know ... old device) all day (6/10/2023) until suddenly I could no longer deploy my app to it. I use this device to test functionality and I finalize designs using the simulator. My test device is running iOS v15.7.6, and was just updated today (6/10/2023), but I had been able to deploy to it after the update until now. The error I get is:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: C:\Users\Presc.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.5.1\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll. OML_iOS C:\Users\Presc\source\repos\MY_APP\MY_APP\SGEN
```

I’m using Visual Studio 2022 v17.6.2.
I've tried many suggestions I found on StackOverflow and other sites, but nothing seems to work.  I've also tried cleaning and rebuilding, no luck there either.  System.Buffers is (apparently) a NuGet package and it is not even installed on this project, it might be getting installed automatically, but I really have no idea if that’s the case. I was able to run the app on the iPhone 14 simulator and execute the functionality, but it was awful slow and buggy that’s why I use this old device to test functionality. But now, today (6/11/2023), the app on the simulator keeps "stopping", no errors, IDE doesn't crash and if I restart the app on the simulator, it is (apparently) still connected to the debugger because if I stop the app on the simulator it stops the app in the IDE.  But now I'm dead in the water, can't do anything.  Anyone know what’s going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I THOUGHT I tried all suggestions I found on StackOverFlow and other sites, apparently not.  I was browsing through my apps `Project->MY_APP Properties` and noticed that the `Generate serialization assembly` option on the `Build` was set to `On`, I had read on one of the aforementioned sites to try setting this option `Off`.  So I did, now I am able to deploy the app to my test device again.  Not sure how I missed that, but I did.  I have no idea what I changed in my app to trigger this as a problem, as I was able to deploy the app to the device before and suddenly I couldn't, VERY annoying not knowing.  For those of you who are having the same issue, I'll post the steps here for Visual Studio 2022 (same for VS 2019),.

1. click on `Projects` on the main IDE menu
2. Select `YourApp Properties`, substitute your projects name for `YourApp`
3. On the project properties tab, select `Build` from the menu on the left side menu, NOT `iOS Build`.
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and you'll find `Generate Serialization assembly` as the last option.
5. Set it to `Off`.

This worked for me, hopefully this will work for you too.

Comment: Excellent! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.